# How to get shortest representation of an enum flags value?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I want to produce the shortest (or one of the shortest) possible combination(s) of the enum fields that would result in a particular enum value. What would be the best algorithm to accomplish this?

For example, say I have the enum:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    One = 1, 
    Two = 2,
    Three = One | Two,
    Four = 4,
    Six = Two | Four,
    Eight = 8,
    All = One | Two | Four | Eight
 }
```

Now for example for the value `7` I would like my function to output either `"One | Six"` or `"Three | Six"`.

Edit: Of course `Three | Four` would be a valid output as well.

Comment: Why `"Three | Six"` and not `"Three | Four"`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Or indeed, `One | Six`

Comment: "Why `Three | Six`" - either a typo or because both `Three` and `Six` share the `Two` flag and wouldn't duplicate the flag?  Follow-up question that I'm interested in, what is this for?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: That is already part of the question :)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: What do you mean by flag duplication? And what flag would be duplicated in the case of `"Three | Four"`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Don't know, I saw it possibly de-duplicated as `One | Two | Four`. I don't care about duplication in `Three | Four` as I was talking about `Three | Six`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I just meant that there would be no shorter, cleverer algorithm than brute force, and my "proof" (a term I'm using very loosely!) is that we can't make use of any known predefined combination of values.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: My comment was aimed at your second comment.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Doh! Sorries!

Comment: @Adam: To answer what this is for, it basically for a UI editor for a flags enum whose output should be a C# expression, and I want this expression to be as short as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are basically asking for is minimum set cover, a problem known to be NP Complete. Fortunately, that doesn't mean that you can't solve it for small cases such as this. You can also get a `O(logn)` approximation via the greedy algorithm.

If there is no particular structure to your enum values, then you won't be able to do much better than brute force for a general exact solution. If you know that your enums have a particular structure, then you can often due much better via things like graph partitioning or CSP + backtracking.

Comment: Is this also a special case of the ["Coin Problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) where the "coins" have values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8 and 15?

Comment: @Me: Actually, it is more a special case of the ["Change Making"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) problem.

Comment: @Matthew, it's not quite the changemaking problem because overlap is allowed. You're taking the bitwise or, not adding.

Comment: Thanks, the minimum set cover was exactly what the doctor ordered. (and of course it's NP complete, just like every other problem I seem to encounter these days ;)